# Wired 360 controller doesn't seem to work with C64 vice emulator?

Tags: retropie, joystick

Just got my retro pie set up.  Played some great old SNES games with my xbox 360 wired usb controller, but had no luck with my C64 Vice Emulator games.  Got some C64 the games to load, but was unable to get the controller or buttons to make any actions.  Thoughts? Advise Help please?

Comment: Try to follow this guide about controls: https://github.com/RetroPie/RetroPie-Setup/wiki/Commodore-64

Answer (score 1):

The Raspberry Pi needs a special driver for Xbox 360 controller compatibility. To download this driver, enter the command `sudo apt-get install xboxdrv`. RetroPie should immediately recognize the controller's input.

This is a good tutorial for this as well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DYmPPx3jh9A